# Way to get Class, Method, Line number info for specific log4j functions

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

Is there a way to only get the class name, method name and line number for specific methods in log4j such as fatal or error? I dont need that info for info and trace.

Comment: you need this for custom logs or for predefined libraries also? @user

Comment: Custom logs for my applications

Comment: so in the config file you need to provide log level right to get specific log, so for the `ERROR` and `FATAL` you can add that line which prints method name and line number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `Appender` can specify one and only one pattern.
So you should probably create two Apppenders : one for the logs above the error level and another one for the logs equal or superior to the error level.

You could use the [`ThresholdFilter` feature](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/filters.html) for the Appender that logs the errors, for example as this one :

```
  <Appenders>
    <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="logs/app.log"
                 filePattern="logs/app-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}.log.gz">
      <ThresholdFilter level="ERROR" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
      <PatternLayout>
        <pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</pattern>
      </PatternLayout>
      <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
    </RollingFile>
  </Appenders>
```

It if matters to have the whole logs in a same file you could still merge them.